# WebSocket | net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I've tried to build up a WebSocket connection between a PHP Websocket server and JavaScript. It looks like the server is running, but I can't build up a connection.

Every time I've tried to build up a connection I've got an error, which says:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:1414/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Is there anyone here who knows the solution for this problem?

By the way, I'm using XAMPP, on a Windows device, to host the PHP server, which is running on port `80`

**PHP server:**

```
<?php
// Error Reporting und Zeitlimit für Serverbetrieb setzen
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
set_time_limit (0);

$host = 'localhost'; // Serverhost auf der gelauscht werden soll
$port = 1414; // Port auf dem Verbindungen angenommen werden sollen

// Socket erstellen
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Socket an Adresse und Port binden
socket_bind($sock, $host, $port);

// An Port lauschen
socket_listen($sock);

$sockets = array($sock);
$arClients = array();

while (true)
{

echo "Warte auf Verbindung...rn";

$sockets_change = $sockets;
$ready = socket_select($sockets_change, $write = null, $expect = null, null);

echo "Verbindung angenommen.rn";

foreach($sockets_change as $s)
{
if ($s == $sock)
{
// Änderung am Serversocket
$client = socket_accept($sock);
array_push($sockets, $client);
print_r($sockets);
}
else
{
// Eingehende Nachrichten der Clientsockets
$bytes = @socket_recv($s, $buffer, 2048, 0);
}
}
}
 ?>
```

JavaScript code:

```
  webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:1414');
  webSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
```

Comment: What is the WebSocket build in - Javascript, php or something else? You are using `ws` as the protocol - you are running from a non ssl page presumably?

Comment: The WebSocket is built in php. And yes I'm not using ssl.

Comment: there is a lot of potential points of failure but without seeing the javascript and php or knowing the details of possible infrastructure which might affect things this is tricky to answer. Consider adding sufficient code to replicate the issue

Comment: Okay I've added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.
I've just changed the port to 80
Now it's should look like this:

> ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80